# Event System PublishEventArgs page subscribe is not being triggered

Tags: publishing, event-system

In my 2011 Event System, I'm subscribing to two events:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, CheckInEventArgs>(OnComponentCheckedInPost, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<Page, PublishEventArgs>(OnPagePublishPre, EventPhases.Initiated);
```

Inside `OnComponentCheckedInPost` method, I have code that creates a page, attaches the component presentation to it and then finally, calls the following method that publishes the page:

```
public static void PublishPage(IdentifiableObject item, PublicationTarget publicationTarget, bool rollBackOnFailure, bool includeComponentLinks, PublishPriority publishPriority)
{
    IEnumerable<IdentifiableObject> items = new List<IdentifiableObject> { item };
    IEnumerable<PublicationTarget> targets = new List<PublicationTarget> { publicationTarget };
    PublishInstruction instruction = new PublishInstruction(item.Session) 
    {
        DeployAt = DateTime.Now,
        MaximumNumberOfRenderFailures = 5,
        RenderInstruction = new RenderInstruction(item.Session),
        RenderInstruction.RenderMode = RenderMode.Publish,
        ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstruction(item.Session),
        ResolveInstruction.IncludeComponentLinks = includeComponentLinks,
        RollbackOnFailure = rollBackOnFailure,
        StartAt = DateTime.MinValue
    };
    PublishEngine.Publish(items, instruction, targets, publishPriority);
}
```

Inside `OnPagePublishPre`, I have code that checks the publication title and and then executes some additional logic:

```
private void OnPagePublishPre(Page page, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
    Publication publication = page.ContextRepository as Publication;
    if (publication != null) {
        if (publication.Title.ToLower == "my publication") {
            //Do something
        }
    }    
}
```

Both events trigger fine on their own. If I create/save a component **NOT** inside "my publication", it creates the corresponding page and publishes it successfully. Similarly, if I publish an existing page **INSIDE** "my publication", it successfully fires the `OnPagePublishPre` method and executes the code.

The problems occurs when I create/save a component **INSIDE** "my publication" which creates and publishes the page, but **DOES NOT** trigger the `OnPagePublishPre` method. I have verified this by attaching to the TcmPublisher.exe and TcmServiceHost.exe processes and stepping through the code. I have also tried different options for the second event: Subscribe instead of SubscribeAsync, TransactionCommitted instead of Initiated and all possible combinations as well as the EventSubscriptionOrder.

After further research, I was able to find a solution by instead subscribing to `EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<Page, SetPublishStateEventArgs>(OnPagePublishPre, EventPhases.Initiated)` and then checking `args.IsPublished` to see if the page was published or unpublished.

However, I would still like to know how to trigger the original subscription (if possible) - for my use case, I don't care if the page is actually successfully published or not. All I need to know is that it was sent to publish in order to execute the business logic.

1. Why is the PublishPage code not firing `EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<Page, PublishEventArgs...;`? Is there anything missing with this code?
2. How is the 2011 event system working in this case? Does it have to do with the EventSubscription order or is there yet another subscription that I can use?

Even though I already have a solution, any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So to get my head around this, basically you are saying that when you Publish a Page, your `OnPagePublishPre` is triggered, but it is not triggered by the `PublishEngine.Publish(...)` call in your `PublishPage` method?

Comment: I think regardless the problem that you are having should be identified and fixed as the solution that you currently have of using `SetPublishStateEventArgs` will not work always. This event is triggered only when the publishing is successful.  
When you mention that creating/saving a component not inside "my publication" creates and page and publishes it, are you sure that the events are also triggered? You mention in the second case that is the publish an existing page inside "my publication " it triggers `OnPagePublishPre` not the earlier case.

Comment: Since you state in your comments on the answers you have solved this, could you post an answer of yourself with the details and accept that so we have a clear question and an accepted answer for future reference?

Answer (score 2):

After further debugging, the "PublishEventArgs" is indeed firing. I was able to finally see it by attaching to dllhost.exe and dllhost3g.exe processes.

Answer (score 1):

Are these the only two custom events in the implementation? Have you checkedif there is anything in the event viewer. events registered are fired in the sequene mentionedin the cm config.if u have any other event sys them DLL pl remove those for debugging purposes and only keep this one

Comment: Why would other Event Handler DLLs interfere with debugging this one?

Comment: May be there are other event system dlls which are throwing exceptions before this one gets fired.

Comment: Yes, I tried to simplify my original question by not including the part about the additional DLL that was actually throwing the exception. After further debugging, the "PublishEventArgs" is indeed firing. I was able to finally see it by attaching to dllhost.exe and dllhost3g.exe processes.

Answer (score 0):

One of your methods is public, while the one that isn't firing is private.  Did you try making it public as well?

Comment: None of the methods need to be public, as long as they are in the same class. The class extending `TcmExtension` needs to be public and the constructor of it of course.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is working fine without having to switch to public.